# Getting value attribute doesn't get current value of input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to write a program, so I can type IP address numbers between 0 and 255. My code works in IE, but not in Firefox or Chrome.

```js
function check(obj) {
  var txt = obj.getAttribute("value");
  txt = parseInt(txt);
  if (txt > 255 || txt < 0) {
    alert("must between 0 and 255");
    obj.focus();
    obj.select();
  } else {
    if (txt > 25) {
      var next = parseInt(obj.getAttribute("id")) + 1;
      if (next < 5) {
        document.getElementById(next.toString()).focus();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="1" onkeyup="check(this);" />
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="2" onkeyup="check(this);" />
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="3" onkeyup="check(this);" />
<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="4" onkeyup="check(this);" />
```

Comment: Looks like an IE bug (in that it shouldn't work there either) - I believe `obj.getAttribute("value");` _should_ give the original value of the attribute, not the currently typed value.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Could you explain exactly what problems you're having?

Comment: E.g., you should be using `obj.value`, not `obj.getAttribute("value")`.

Comment: I can't find a clean dupetarget for this, they all are obscured by jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current value of an `input` is reflected by its `value` *property*, not the `value` *attribute*. If IE is giving you the current value via `getAttribute`, it's a bug in IE.

You should be using `obj.value`, not `obj.getAttribute("value")`.

---

It's a bit confusing. :-) The `value` *attribute* defines the *default value* for the `input`, not its current value. It doesn't change when the user changes it. There is no *attribute* for the current value, you access it via the `value` property. Some attributes are reflected by properties with the same name (`id`, for instance), but `value` isn't one of them. (There is a property that reflects the `value` attribute: `defaultValue`. But again, it's the default, not the current value.)

Comment: So I understand.  The document will not change when I type. So getAttribute will get nothing.