# How can I skip one input type from being included in a serializedArray() Function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I want to skip a particular input type (responsible for my row ID for editing). However, in the code below, the first console.log(formObject.rowId) returns a value, while after the serializedArray() the second console.log(formObject.rowId) returns an undefined.

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
console.log(formObject.rowId)
            var formObject = $("#myForm :input[value!='']").serializeArray()
            formObject.push({
              name: 'myfile',
              value: myfile
            })
console.log(formObject.rowId)
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
setTimeout(function() {$('#myModal').modal('hide');}, 3000);
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>Data added/updated successfully.</div>";
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

Heres the HTML Element for the input type that I want to skip:

```
 <input type="text" id="rowId" name="rowId" value="" style="display: none">
```

Comment: [Dont give it a `name` attribute.](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: @Lain still returns an undefined :(

Comment: @Potatou_ - What makes you think that?

Comment: @Potatou_ - Unrelated, but beware that `[value!='']` in a CSS selector does not do what you probably want it to do. It **doesn't** check to see if fields have values, it checks to see if they have *default* values; [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210254/javascript-program-works-well-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-and-chrome-to-fill-in-i). If you want to filter out fields that don't have a value in them, you'll have to do that via `filter` before calling `serializeArray`, something like: `$("#myForm :input").filter((input) => $(input).val().trim()).serializeArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) ignores fields that don't have a `name`:

```js
console.log($("#the-form").serializeArray());
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
    <input type="text" name="x">
    <input type="text" id="rowId" value="" style="display: none">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how only the `name="x"` was included, not the other `input`.

Comment: It does skip it, but how can I now reference my formObject.rowId once I pass it to the processForm()?

Comment: @Potatou_ - It has an `id`, so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo selector (or JQuery [`.not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)) is viable?

Furthermore: the selector `#myForm :input[value!='']` seems not to work. Using `$(":input[value!='']")` does - see snippet.

```js
console.log(`all input except #rowId => [${
  [...document.querySelectorAll("input:not(#rowId)")]
    .map(v => `input#${v.id}`)}]`);

console.log(`all input except display:none => [${
  [...document.querySelectorAll("input:not([style*='display:none'])")]
    .map(v => `input#${v.id}`)}]`);

console.log(`all input except #rowId JQuery: [${
  $.map($(":input[value!='']").not(`#rowId`), v => `input#${v.id}`)}]`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm ">
  <input type="text" id="somerowid1" value="row1">
  <input type="text" id="rowId" ame="rowId" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="somerowid2" value="row2">
</form>
```