# Why do these generate two separate outcome?

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I created a my very first QR Code Scanner

my first version was like this

```
function decodeQRCode(photo) {
  const scanner = new BarcodeDetector({
    formats: ['qr_code']
  })
  scanner.detect(photo)
    .then((barcodes) => {
      bar_length = barcodes.length
      if (bar_length != 0) {
        barcodes.forEach(
          (barcode) =>
          input.setAttribute("value", barcode.rawValue),
        );

        input.addEventListener('input', form.submit())
        setTimeout(takepicture, 3000);
        console.log("success")

      } else {
        setTimeout(takepicture, 1500);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

my second version looks like this

```
function decodeQRCode(photo) {
  const scanner = new BarcodeDetector({
    formats: ['qr_code']
  })
  setTimeout(() => {
    scanner.detect(photo)
      .then((barcodes) => {
        bar_length = barcodes.length
        if (bar_length != 0) {
          barcodes.forEach(
            (barcode) =>
            input.setAttribute("value", barcode.rawValue)
          );

          input.addEventListener('input', form.submit())

        } else {
          takepicture()
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, 3000)
```

On my 1st version it is set to scan qrcodes every 3 seconds, because I set it to call`function takepicture()` with a 3 seconds delay but the `console.log("success")` continuously prints out "success" until I point the camera away from the QRCode

On my 2nd version, I still used setTimeout but with arrow function and it is doing the way I wanted it to do which is scan every 3 seconds

I just dont really know why it's continuously printing on my first version, both are set to call `function takepicture()` with a 3 seconds delay but just in a different approach

Comment: The first one only scans the barcodes once, the second one scans the barcodes every 3 seconds.

Comment: `input.addEventListener('input', form.submit())` <-- it is calling submit, it is not assigning submit to the event handler.

Comment: The `barcodes.forEach()` loop doesn't make much sense. You're overwriting the input value each time through the loop, so it just gets the value from the last barcode in the array.

Comment: Also, `input.setAttribute("value", barcode.rawValue)` isn't how you set the value of an input. That's one way to set the *default* value of an input, not the current value. The correct way to set the current value of an input is `input.value = barcode.rawValue;` More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210254/javascript-program-works-well-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-and-chrome-to-fill-in-i

Comment: @Barmar I'm using ```barcodes.forEach()``` to access the data of the qr-Code, I did manage to figure out another way of getting the value which is ```barcodes[0]['rawValue']```, maybe using ```forEach``` was not efficient

Comment: Thank you for pointing these out :) since I'm only studying by myself and I don't really know which are the best practices/approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: `setTimeout(takepicture, 3000);` acts like an [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) function. That means, the code executes that line and then continues with the remainder of the code without waiting for what happens inside the function (which is waiting for 3 seconds and then calling `takepicture`).

In your second version you have wrapped all the code inside the `setTimeout` function, which forces the code to wait for 3 seconds before executing that code.

In other words:

```
setTimeout(takepicture, 3000);
console.log("success");
```

will print "success" immediately, because the code does not wait for the `setTimeout` function to complete.

But:

```
setTimeout(() => {console.log("success");}, 3000);
```

Will wait 3 seconds before printing "success".

Because your first snippet executes the code every time a qr code is detected, and it does not wait for the set timeout function to complete, you will therefore continuously get success messages.

For more information, see this article on [Asynchronous Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

Hope that helps.